# Difference between various theories of liquid crystals

Tags: liquid-crystal

Can somebody explain as to what is the difference between various theories of liquid crystals?

1. Maier-Saupe Theory
2. Onsager Theory
3. Landau theory

What's the advantages and disadvantages or limitations of each approach?